# Output to csv file dumps the data to browser but not dump to file

Tags: csv, web, go, beego

I tried to ouput some data to csv file in golang beego framework, here is my code

```
records := make([][]string,len(devicesData))

for k,v := range devicesData{
    records[k] = []string{v.Fields.Country,v.Fields.Imei[0],v.Fields.Number[0]}
}

writer := csv.NewWriter(this.Controller.Ctx.ResponseWriter)
for _, record := range records {
    err := writer.Write(record)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }
}

this.Ctx.Output.Header("Content-Type", "application/csv")
this.Ctx.Output.Header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyVerySpecial.csv")

    writer.Flush()
```

However, it only shows the record data in browser, it cannot download the file. I have some loging controller and filter function before this download file controller, I do not whether it is affected. What's wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: FYI (you probably know this, I assume the above code was simplified for the question; but for other readers), if you're going to loop per record anyway you could just call `Write([]string{…})` per record rather than storing it in a `[][]string`. If however you do want to process them all first and store them in a `[][]string` then you can use [`WriteAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Writer.WriteAll) to write all the records instead of looping again yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You should always set response headers **first** and only after that start writing any data to the output. I know you called `writer.Flush()` after setting header fields, but that is no guarantee whatsoever that data will not be flushed or sent before that - which will imply default headers being sent. After this no additional headers can be sent or changed.

Also the proper mime type for CSV is `text/csv` not `application/csv` ([rfc4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)).

Also the headers are more like a *"proposal"* to the browser. That's one thing you suggest the response is a file to be saved, but from the server side you can't force the browser to really save the response to a file and not display it.

See [rfc1806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1806.txt), [rfc2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) and [rfc6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) for more details about the `"Content-Disposition"` header field. Basically it communicates presentation information.

> The Content-Disposition response header field is used to convey
> additional information about how to process the response payload, and
> also can be used to attach additional metadata, such as the filename
> to use when saving the response payload locally.