# How to make client open save file dialog when downloading a file

Tags: http, go, web, download

I want the browser to show or open a file save dialog box to save the file I send when user clicks on the download file button.

My server side code for download:

```
func Download(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    url := "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/bc/Wiki.png"

    timeout := time.Duration(5) * time.Second
    transport := &http.Transport{
        ResponseHeaderTimeout: timeout,
        Dial: func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            return net.DialTimeout(network, addr, timeout)
        },
        DisableKeepAlives: true,
    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: transport,
    }
    resp, err := client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    //copy the relevant headers. If you want to preserve the downloaded file name, extract it with go's url parser.
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "form-data; filename=Wiki.png")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", r.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", r.Header.Get("Content-Length"))
    //dialog.File().Filter("XML files", "xml").Title("Export to XML").Save()
    //stream the body to the client without fully loading it into memory
    io.Copy(w, resp.Body)
}
```

Comment: Set the `attachment` not `form-data` content disposition type.

Comment: I try set "attachment " but not show dialog from brower

Comment: You also set content type and length from a bad "source". See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

If you intend the response to be saved at the client side, use the `"attachment"` content disposition type. This is detailed in [rfc2183](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt), section 2.2:

> 2.2  The Attachment Disposition Type
>
> Bodyparts can be designated `attachment' to indicate that they are
>      separate from the main body of the mail message, and that their
>      display should not be automatic, but contingent upon some further
>      action of the user.  The MUA might instead present the user of a
>      bitmap terminal with an iconic representation of the attachments, or,
>      on character terminals, with a list of attachments from which the
>      user could select for viewing or storage.

So set it like this:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Wiki.png")
```

Also when setting headers of your response writer `w`, copy the fields from the response you make, not from the incoming request:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", resp.Header.Get("Content-Type"))
w.Header().Set("Content-Length", resp.Header.Get("Content-Length"))
```

Also note that the headers are more like a *"proposal"* to the browser. That's one thing you suggest the response is a file to be saved, but from the server side you can't force the browser to really save the response to a file and not display it.

See related question: [Golang beego output to csv file dumps the data to browser but not dump to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31018042/golang-beego-output-to-csv-file-dumps-the-data-to-browser-but-not-dump-to-file/31019074#31019074)

Comment: Not work for me,
I use chrome to download.
With IE, the default is to allow the directory to save the download.
I'm understanding that it depends on the browser

Comment: "Not work for me" --- explain what that means. What you see and what you expect to see?

Comment: My expectation is that after click button download, then open dialog select a folder to save the file.But I understand that in addition to code implementation, you need settings to be able to open the browser dialog. Thank you!